# Is there any course video for lattice cryptography?

Tags: lattice-crypto

Recently, I started doing research about Lattice Based Cryptography. and searched on YouTube a lot of public talks or seminars about it.

But is there any course video (graduated course) related to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from 2012, so it's not the most up to day. However, the 2nd BIU winter school was on this topic, and all of the slides and videos can be found online. The lecturers were Craig Gentry, Vadim Lyubashevsky, Chris Peikert and Oded Regev. The link is here: https://cyber.biu.ac.il/event/the-2nd-biu-winter-school/.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Hope someday some one would share the full semester course video online.